# How pass params and save in db

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, relationship

have the relationships:

(my code is in portuguese)

Order

```
class Pedido < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :pessoa
```

Person

```
class Pessoa < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :usuario
  has_many :enderecos
  has_many :pedidos

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :enderecos
end
```

User

```
class Usuario < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :pessoas
  has_many :pedidos, through: :pessoas

end
```

carrinhos_controller.rb

```
def checkout
    @pedido = current_usuario.pedidos.build
  end
```

In migration `Person` have `usuario_id`, `Order` have `pessoa_id` and others...
When I finish an order, the `pessoa_id` is null and does not save on database, why??

More codes:
pedidos_controller.rb

```
class PedidosController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_usuario!

  # Criar pedido
  def create
    @pedido = current_usuario.pedidos.build(pedido_params)
    if @pedido.save
      @pedido.construir_cache_item_carrinho(carrinho_atual)
      @pedido.calcular_total!(carrinho_atual)
      carrinho_atual.limpar!
      #OrdemDeServico.new(carrinho_atual, @pedido).encomendar_pedido!
      redirect_to pedido_path(@pedido.token)
    else
      render "carrinho/checkout"
    end
  end
```

Comment: Why do you have `User` and `Person` as different models?

Comment: Because aren't equals, user is different of person, each one have specific function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code:

```
def checkout
 @pedido = current_usuario.pedidos.build
 @pedido.save
end
```

If you are using `build` or `new`, then you have to use `save` method after that. Otherwise you can use direct `create` method.

Answer (score 0):

`build` does not save to the DB. Either save afterwards (`@pedido.save`) or try `@pedido = current_usuario.pedidos.create`

Comment: sorry, I forgot other part... look now please

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are using something like a nested form to post the parameters. I often use the [nested_form gem by Ryan Bates](https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form).

If you look careful at the usage you can find some useful insights.
Also take care of the **strong_parameters**: it is required to declare in the controller which params you want to permit.

Comment: Thanks, but using this gem my error continue... I need make something that  save pessoa_id on database. It is null yet.